# Best way to implement outer / inner loop in Elixir

Tags: elixir

What would be the best / correct way to implement the following code in Elixir:

```
 foreach( var item in items) {

  foreach(var num in get_nums_from(item)) {

        yield return is_valid(num) ? num : -1;
 }  }
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A free translation of the loop will be something like:

```
Enum.flat_map(items, fn (item) ->
  Enum.map(get_nums_from(item), fn (num) ->
    if is_valid?(num), do: num, else: -1
  end)
end)
```

If you also want to preserve the lazy character of the iteration (which I think the .net version will have) you need to use Stream instead, to create a lazy sequence:

```
Stream.flat_map(items, fn (item) ->
  Stream.map(get_nums_from(item), fn (num) ->
    if is_valid?(num), do: num, else: -1
  end)
end)
```

Answer (score 6):

Another approach, assuming laziness is not a requirement, is a list comprehension:

`for item <- items, num <- get_nums_from(item) do
  if is_valid?(num), do: num, else: -1
end`

Answer (score 6):

Bitwalker's response answers your question nicely; however, what are you doing with all those
-1s?   If you're just going to filter them out later, consider something
like:

```
for i <- items, num <- get_nums_from(item), is_valid?(num), do: num
```

In executable terms that looks like

```
iex(2)> for i <- [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]], j <- i, rem(j, 2) == 0, do: j
[2, 4, 6, 8]
```

Or maybe give a look at Enum.filter/2.